# Slash commands not giving any response discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been learning discord.js following the official docs, but I'm unable to get the bot to reply to the slash ( / ) commands

```
//This is the ping.js command file

const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('pings')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    },
};
```

```
//This is the command handling / interaction handling


const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    // Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    // Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}


//construct and prepare an instance for the REST module
const rest = new REST().setToken(discordToken);

//deploy the commands
(async () =>{
    try{
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(discordClientID),
            {body:commands},
        )

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
    } catch (err){
        console.error(err);
    }
})

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction =>{
    if(!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    console.log(interaction);

    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command){
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found`);
        return;
    }

    try{
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (err){
        console.error(err);
        if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred){
            await interaction.followUp({content: 'There was an error while executing this command', ephemeral: true});
        }else{
            await interaction.reply({content: 'There was an error while executing this command', ephemeral: true});
        }
    }
});
```

Sorry if the code is long, but this is all I have. So far I know that whenever I type /pings the bot should response with "Pong!" but all I see is the slash commands of the other bots I have in the server. This is not comming from the app itself, since I have added the bot with this two scopes "bot" "application.commands" as well as the "slash commands" so I guess this should be working just fine...

I was trying to find a useful answer here, but all of them are outdated, and are no longer working.